# Behaviour of a star as it approaches Ultrarelativistc limit

Tags: special-relativity, astrophysics, stars, virial-theorem, white-dwarfs

By considering the potential energy of a degenerate
star of mass
$M$
and radius
$R$, 
I can use dimensional arguments to show that the radius
of the star depends on its mass as:

$$  R ∝  M^\frac{2-n}{4-3n}$$

Where in the non-relativistic regime $n = 5/3$
whilst in ultra-relativitic $n = 4/3$

By taking $n = 5/3$ I can see that non-relativistically

$$ R ∝ M^\frac{-1}{3} $$

Could someone explain to me the physical nature of what happens when $n = 4/3$ and it becomes relativistic as I am unsure what

$$ R ∝ M^{\infty}$$ means physically.

Comment: Have you seen https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/White_dwarf#Mass%E2%80%93radius_relationship_and_mass_limit ? In particular, see the section titled *Mass–radius relationship and mass limit*.

Answer (score 2):

It means, that
$$ M \propto R^0$$
so that if you did have a star governed by a relativistic polytrope, there is only one mass the star can have. This is the "classic" Chandrasekhar mass, at which the radius shrinks to nothing and the density increases to infinity.

In practice, the Chandrasekhar mass is itself inconsistent with a true relativistic treatment since it ignores the kinetic energy contribution to the gravitating mass. Inclusion of this in a full GR treatment leads to instability and collapse at a finite density and at a slightly lower mass.